# Redeploying SSIS packages - Cache?

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2008-r2

We have noticed an issue recently that redeployed SSIS packages sometime don't seem to include the latest changes... When I search the dtsx using notepad I see the amended script in the code so the changes are definitely there.

My assumption was that script components of SSIS packages are eventually compiled into an assembly somewhere in the process - this is quite likely since I would imagine C# code cannot run without something compiling it first. So in theory if these assemblies would then end up being cached and not immediately overwritten (for some reason) that would explain this issue.

The only "evidence" that makes me think that my theory is correct is if I keep running the package at some point it suddenly shifts to the new code.

However, so far I haven't found why and how this is happening, if is... Can anybody help?

**UPDATE:** 
MSDN says: "Unlike earlier versions where you could indicate whether the scripts were precompiled, all scripts are precompiled in SQL Server 2008 Integration Services (SSIS) and later versions." - If by *pre-compiled* they mean that instead of the actual package a pre-compiled version runs (I think this because the package itself does not seem to be compiled since the code is visible in Notepad) there must be a way to force the engine to overwrite the pre-compiled assembly... but how?

**UPDATE:**
One of the four core components of SSIS is the *SQL ServerIntegration Services service*, which is a windows service. Apparently this service will cache component/task metadata so that the SSIS runtime engine can poll the cache to see what is installed, which may help speed up package load times. However, if the packages are stored in the file system (not in SQL Integration Services) and executed by Agent Jobs, the agent job will use the 64 bit version of DTEXEC to execute the packages. I haven't yet found evidence that any caching would be involved there, but there are certainly options to check a number of parameters in the validation phase of the execution, such as version numbers - may be for a reason.

Comment: Just to say we have the same exact issue here today. Restarting the agent nor the SQLSISS helps.

Comment: What did the trick was adding and removing a column from a table involved. Clearly, this is not the way to go and we are certainly interested in the answer to this question

Comment: Also: I think the cache is stored somewhere on disk because it survived a server reboot

Comment: As a heads up: we encountered the same issue again but in a production deploy this week. Sadly it took two days before I realised this was the problem.

Answer (score 4):

Have you looked at sysssispackages to compare the version build number of the package in msdb to your build number in Visual Studio / SSIS?

```
SELECT name, verbuild
FROM msdb.dbo.sysssispackages
WHERE name LIKE '%bla%'
```

(Adjust WHERE-clause as necessary to find your package. Do NOT ever "SELECT * FROM msdb.dbo.sysssispackages" as it contains the package XML in one of the columns.)

And in Visual Studio, open the package, then right-click at the background of the package and select *"Properties"* from the context menu. Look at the field VersionBuild. It should match the number from the SELECT above!

I know this is not an actual solution to your problem but it may help locate where the cause of the problem is. If the number is older, it means that your package deployment did not work.

Comment: +1 Good suggestion. We'll try to reproduce the problem and check out whether this might help us to at least indicate that this is the problem.  Obviously we're still looking for an actual solution to the problem.

Comment: +cmenke: your query returns 8 rows: SqlTraceCollect, SqlTraceUpload, TSQLQueryCollect, TSQLQueryUpload, PerfCountersCollect, PerfCountersUpload, QueryActivityCollect, QueryActivityUpload. Obviously none of those are my ssis. Our deployment process is as follows: our msi package just copies the dtsx to a folder, alters configuration file (for conn info etc). Then our scheduler runs dtexec /F "%dtsfile%" /Rep EPW /Conf %dtsconfig% > %logfile% Do we need to do something else?

Comment: Ahhhh, you are running the packages from the file system and not from within SSIS' own database MSDB. In that case my comment doesn't apply to your problem.
I have very little experience with executing packages from the file system, but at least it means you don't have to worry about the Deployment Utility not doing its job.

Comment: Why would I run them from MSDB? Is there a big advantage?

Comment: In my opinion its easier to run from MSDB, you don't have to worry about getting the path to the package right, the package cannot become "lost" (from a network share disconnecting, for example). Its pretty much self contained: You deploy it to MSDB, then you create an SQL Server Agent Job with Run SSIS Package step. You can actually select the package to run from a drop box in the assistant. Plus you get the Job Log afterwards. I guess it depends on whether you want to run jobs actively or have them start on their own [in the middle of the night].

Comment: @cmenke, I have this problem, please help here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37238713/installation-wizard-shows-its-success-however-ssis-package-is-not-getting-ins

Answer (score 4):

This sounds somewhat familiar to something I ran into a while back. Unfortunately, I don't remember exactly **when** I ran into this (so I can't check for sure), but I **believe** the fix I found was to make sure that I explicitly invoked the `Build | Build st_5bd541c294054c25b9e7eb55b92bd0e2` command from the script editor (VSTA) menu before closing the window. (The specific project name will be different for each script, obviously, since it's based on a GUID; however, there will only be one possible submenu under `Build`.)

Explicitly invoking the `Build` command ensures that the binary code for the script gets ASCII-encoded and saved in the XML of the resulting .dtsx file. I'd gotten used to SSIS 2005 always building for me whenever I closed the script editor. Apparently, there are bizarre edge cases where SSIS 2008 doesn't always build the script project when the editor closes.

BTW, the precompiled binaries appear to be stored in a tag of the source XML called `BinaryItem`:

```xml
  <DTS:Executable DTS:ExecutableType="Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.ScriptTask, Microsoft.SqlServer.ScriptTask, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" DTS:ThreadHint="0">
    <DTS:Property DTS:Name="ObjectName">SCR_StepOne</DTS:Property>
    <DTS:ObjectData>
      <ScriptProject Name="ST_5bd541c294054c25b9e7eb55b92bd0e2" VSTAMajorVersion="2" VSTAMinorVersion="1" Language="CSharp" EntryPoint="Main" ReadOnlyVariables="User::FileOneName,User::OutputFolder" ReadWriteVariables="">
        <BinaryItem Name="\bin\release\st_5bd541c294054c25b9e7eb55b92bd0e2.csproj.dll">
          TVqQAAMAAAAEAAAA//8AALgAAAAAAAAAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
          AAAAgAAAAA4fug4AtAnNIbgBTM0hVGhpcyBwcm9ncmFtIGNhbm5vdCBiZSBydW4gaW4gRE9TIG1v
          ZGUuDQ0KJAAAAAAAAABQRQAATAEDADuOb04AAAAAAAAAAOAAAiELAQgAABAAAAAIAAAAAAAAPi8A
          AAAgAAAAQAAAAABAAAAgAAAAAgAABAAAAAAAAAAEAAAAAAAAAACAAAAAAgAAAAAAAAMAQIUAABAA
```

It might be worth checking your source code control system history to see if that was getting updated for some of those screwy errors.

Caveat: I haven't found official Microsoft documentation on this.

Comment: Am I right in thinking this is only for C# script projects? Thus far we haven't really used those.

Comment: I haven't checked, but I expect it would be the same for either C# or VB.NET projects (I'm pretty sure it's an SSIS 2008 issue).

Comment: I ran into this issue when I made modifications to a script component by editing the .dtsx as XML.  Because it was edited via the XML instead of the designer, the binaries were never recompiled; it was a "Duh?!" moment.  As you say, the fix was to explicitly recompile each of the edited script components.

Comment: I encountered this same issue today and in the past and can confirm this works. I have also previously had to invoke a forced build when upgrading packages from a 32bit to a 64bit environment. It had the same affect of forcing a recompile of the ASCII-encoded binary in the .dtsx file.

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't specifically solve the mystery you have, but if you are running file system-based packages and want to verify that the package that is running is the package you deployed, there is a way to do that.

1. Build your package.
2. Open the properties on your package and note down the "Version Build" property (alternatively, open the .dtsx in notepad and find the DTS:VersionBuild attribute.)
3. Deploy your package.
4. In your SQL Agent job step, go to the Verification tab.
5. Enter the Version Build in the "Verify package build" input box.
6. Execute the job step.

I don't know if this will force SSIS to throw out its cache and get the newly deployed package, but I do know if you modify the .dtsx package's build number by hand and then try to re-run the job step it fails because the package build doesn't match what it's looking for so it is definitely doing a run-time check of that value.

Comment: I think step 3 and 4 are not applicable as we run from filesystem.

Comment: Well, you still "deploy" your job, you just use deploy to the filesystem. And you still have a Verification tab on any SQL Agent job where the subtype is an SSIS Package.