# Installation wizard shows its success , however, SSIS Package is not getting installed

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2008-r2

I have both SQL Server 2008 R2 and 2012 both installed on same server. My SSIS package is developed by BI studio 2008 R2. I have created package manifest file for the installation.

As both SQL Server 2008 R2 and 2012 installed, when I run command:

```
H:\>where dtsinstall.exe
```

it returns these 3 details:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\dtsinstall.exe
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\dtsinstall.exe
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn\dtsinstall.exe
```

So, I forced particular (that are under `\100\`) `dtsinstall.exe` for the installation. Like below:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\dtsinstall.exe" "E:\UAT\Final.SSISDeploymentManifest"
```

and also

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\dtsinstall.exe" "E:\UAT\Final.SSISDeploymentManifest"
```

**Update**

From wizard, i'm giving the things like this:

Sever name - local, User SQL Server Authentication, package path : /folder_name/ under MSDB

select installation folder : E\Folder1\Folder2

yes i have folder id in SQL which is a big hexadecimal number; somehow I want to see the complete path (i.e. E\Folder1\Folder2) by executing query. Is there any query to see and confirm this?

Here , after installation the new packages should be in : E\Folder1\Folder2 and the problem is new packages are not at this location.Its showing me old packages with old installed date.

In both cases, Installation is showing success from the wizard; however, the location where I'm installing is still showing me old dates - means packages are not getting modified. I checked the installation log as well and there are no error. Can any one please tell me if I'm missing something or do I need to check any particular things before installation? Why the actually its not getting installed and dates are also not getting modified? Anyone faced similar problem before?

Is it necessary to uninstall SQL Server 2012 and try? OR it could be a permission issue as may be I have limited permission on UAT server?

**Update:**

I executed this query:

```
use msdb;
select * from dbo.sysssispackages
```

this gave me package details, when I checked the build version of pkg it gave me my new installed build version. However, when I looked into the folder which i selected during the installation show me the old version number, which is quite strange.

Here my question is, is there any way to know , in which folder its actually installing?

I executed this query as well:

```
 select * FROM sysssispackagefolders
```

This gives me folderid but not the path; I want to know the exact path?

Is it that on server its installing but not reflecting in folder somehow?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't you specify the target when you go through the wizard? Something somewhere needs to specify the target (server, path etc.). Perhaps if you open the SSISDeploymentManifest file in notepad and take a look.

Comment: Yes. I have specified everything that are required during installation.

Comment: Don't you specify the target folder in your manifest? I suppose there must be a folderid > name lookup table in SQL also.

Comment: From widzard, i'm giving the things like this:
Sever name - local, User SQL Server Authentication, package path : /folder_name/

select installtion folder : E\Folder1\Folder2

yes i have folder id in SQL which is a big hexadecimal number. What do you mean by "Don'y you the target older in your manifest" ? I opened manifest in notepad and did not found anything name target folder. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: I see a server name and pacakage path in there. Is that what you're after? Perhaps you could enhance your question with these details, including whether you are deploying to MSDB etc. I will tell you I have never used the package deployment wizard because there never seemed to be much benefit. In SQL 2008 I always just ran packages straight from the file system,

Comment: I have updated my question to give more clarification. Its MSDB , SQL server installation.

Comment: I just had a look in my MSDB - looks like folder names are in `select * from msdb.[dbo].[sysssispackagefolders]`. This is a self referencing table. Does this help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17793359/ssis-physical-path